# How To Implement transaction in Business logic layer

Tags: asp.net, database, transactions, transactionscope

I'am using enterprise library data access block in my asp.net application. I want to implement transaction from the Business logic layer, across multiple stored procs. Entlib opens a new connection for database access.
 Does using Transaction Scope in the following way lead to distributed transaction?

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    // calling necessary DAL methods
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Is there better methods to implement transaction from BLL?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about SQL Server as the backend, it depends on the server version. Here is a good article: [DO.NET and System.Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163847.aspx)

I quote:

> The TransactionScope is smart enough
>   not to create a fully distributed
>   transaction with all of its overhead
>   unless it is necessary. If the
>   resource involved in the transaction
>   is volatile, everything will stay in
>   memory and the Microsoft distributed
>   transaction coordinator (DTC) will not
>   be involved. If the resource is a
>   connection to SQL Server 2005, the DTC
>   will not be involved, and SQL Server
>   2005 will handle the transaction. This
>   is equivalent to opening an internal
>   SQL transaction. If SQL Server 2000 is
>   used, it will resolve to using a full
>   DTC transaction.

Comment: Good Article. I checked the Transaction.Current. TransactionInformation.DistributedIdentifier within the transaction scope. value is Guid.Empty {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} So I guess the transaction remains light weight, though i'm doing multiple accesses to the sql server within the same transaction scope.